# Как вернуть второе значение регулярного выражения (C#)?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

```
var find1 = Regex.Match(s,"<td class=.additional-attribute.>(.*?)<", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```

Этому выражения соответствует 5 результатов.
Мне нужно вывести первые 2.

Это не помогает :(

```
var find1 = Regex.Match(s,"<td class=.additional-attribute.>(.*?)<", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[2].Value;
```

(Groups[1] поменял на Groups[2])

Comment: 1) парсить html регулярками неправильно 2) Вы входные данные забыли указать

Comment: 3) `var firstTwo = Regex.Matches(s,"<td class=.additional-attribute.>(.*?)<", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).OfType<Match>().Take(2).ToArray();` ?

Comment: Я только учусь. Все делаю неправильно, знаю :) Ошибка 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Есть альтернатива? Требуется без доп. библиотек. Все это в "урезанной" среде. Без компилятора.

Comment: `Regex.Matches(s,"<td class=.additional-attribute.>(.*?)<", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[0].Value`

Comment: `Match` - один результат. `Matches` - все результаты. Или можно использовать `NextMatch`.

Comment: _Все это в "урезанной" среде._ - в какой именно среде? Почему этой информации нет в самом вопросе? _Без компилятора_ - ???

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить первые два совпадения (тут значения первой захватываемой подмаски), найдите сначала их все с помощью `Regex.Matches`, а потом воспользуйтесь LINQ:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, "(?si)<td class=.additional-attribute.>(.*?)<")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Take(2)                          // Взять первые два
        .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
        .ToList();
```

[Пример кода](https://ideone.com/t6uZJU):

```
var s = "<td class='additional-attribute'>1</td><td class='additional-attribute'>2</td><td class='additional-attribute'>3</td>";
var result = Regex.Matches(s, "(?si)<td class=.additional-attribute.>(.*?)<")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Take(2)
            .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
            .ToList();
foreach (var n in result)
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Результат: `1` и `2`.